# How to get equivalent to subfigure without using floats?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, captions, minipage, subcaption

I understand that floats are supposed to *float*, however, I have a lot of graphical data, and sometimes when I say put it here, I mean exactly, not plus/minus two pages.

I can achieve this using minipages, but it won't have as clean a caption (see below minimum working example). Can anyone give me a workaround which looks exactly like the subfigure, but doesn't float.

I understand my resulting document is not very pretty, but it gets the point across.

```
\documentclass{article} % Article class of KOMA-script with 11pt font and a4 format
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}                                                       % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage{caption} %for images
\usepackage{subcaption} %for sub images

\begin{document}
\section{Doesn't float but not as pretty}
\subsection{A}
The below image details what results we got for subsection A

\centering
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf}
     \captionof{figure}{Test I}
 \end{minipage} ~ %
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf}
     \captionof{figure}{Test II}
 \end{minipage}

\subsection{B}
The below image details what results we got for subsection B

\centering
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf}
     \captionof{figure}{Test I}
 \end{minipage} ~ %
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf}
     \captionof{figure}{Test II}
 \end{minipage}

\subsection{C}
The below image details what results we got for subsection C

\centering
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf}
     \captionof{figure}{Test I}
 \end{minipage} ~ %
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf}
     \captionof{figure}{Test II}
 \end{minipage}

\subsection{D}
The below image details what results we got for subsection D

\centering
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf}
     \captionof{figure}{Test I}
 \end{minipage} ~ %
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf}
     \captionof{figure}{Test II}
 \end{minipage}

\section{Pretty, but keeps floating}
\subsection{A}
The below image details what results we got for subsection A

\begin{figure}[h!]
   \centering
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth} 
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf} 
      \caption{Test I} 
   \end{subfigure}
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf}
      \caption{Test II}
   \end{subfigure}
   \caption{Results for subsection A}
\end{figure}

\subsection{B}
The below image details what results we got for subsection B

\begin{figure}[h!]
   \centering
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth} 
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf} 
      \caption{Test I} 
   \end{subfigure}
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf}
      \caption{Test II}
   \end{subfigure}
   \caption{Results for subsection B}
\end{figure}

\subsection{C}
The below image details what results we got for subsection C

\begin{figure}[h!]
   \centering
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth} 
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf} 
      \caption{Test I} 
   \end{subfigure}
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf}
      \caption{Test II}
   \end{subfigure}
   \caption{Results for subsection C}
\end{figure}

\subsection{D}
The below image details what results we got for subsection D

\begin{figure}[h!]
   \centering
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth} 
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf} 
      \caption{Test I} 
   \end{subfigure}
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf}
      \caption{Test II}
   \end{subfigure}
   \caption{Results for subsection D}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: 1) this is not koma script you are using (comments say otherwise) 2) you should not rely on 0.5+0.5=1 3) normally, `\FloatBarrier \begin{figure}...\end{figure}\FloatBarrier` doesnt float either (from placeins package, there surely are numerous other solutions for this)

Comment: @Bort 1)I am unfamiliar with Koma 2) OK 3) I will try that

Answer (score 4):

I can't recommend making figures not to float. It's right, the caption is just for showing the reader what the figure is about.

However, here's a way to cope with your problem: define an environment where you set up the format for the subfigure caption (otherwise it wouldn't be set, for some reason).

```
\documentclass{article} % Article class of KOMA-script with 11pt font and a4 format

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} %for images
\usepackage{subcaption} %for sub images

\newenvironment{nonfloat}
  {%
   \par\nopagebreak\vspace{\medskipamount}%
   \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
   \captionsetup[subfigure]{
     margin=0pt,font+=small,labelformat=parens,labelsep=space,
     skip=-6pt,list=false,hypcap=false
   }%
  }
  {\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\section{Doesn't float but not as pretty}
\subsection{A}
The below image details what results we got for subsection A

\begin{nonfloat}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf}
  \captionof{subfigure}{Test I}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf}
  \captionof{subfigure}{Test II}
\end{minipage}
\captionof{figure}{Results for subsection A}
\end{nonfloat}

\section{Pretty, but keeps floating}
\subsection{A}
The below image details what results we got for subsection A

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth} 
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf} 
  \caption{Test I} 
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/fov.pdf}
  \caption{Test II}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Results for subsection A}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: the `pdftex` option should never be specified for `graphicx` (nor for `hyperref`); I used `demo` just because I don't have your graphic files, remove it for a production version.

Comment: That failed for me. I get `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)`

Comment: @puk The code I showed is the one I used for producing the image.

Comment: The width of the `minipage` in the `nonfloat` environment should be `\linewidth` rather than `\textwidth` to avoid overfull hboxes in case of using it in e.g. an `itemize` list.

Comment: @John The figure environment is independent of being in a list

Comment: @egreg I was referring to your `nonfloat` environment.

Comment: @John You’re right, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Try use figure option [H] provided by package `float`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} %for images
\usepackage{subcaption} %for sub images
\usepackage{float} %for figure option H

\begin{document}
\section{Doesn't float but not as pretty}
\subsection{A}
The below image details what results we got for subsection A
    \begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{Test I}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
  \caption{Test II}
\end{subfigure}
   \caption{Results for subsection A}
    \end{figure}
\subsection{A}
The below image details what results we got for subsection B
    \begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
    \caption{Test I}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}
  \caption{Test II}
\end{subfigure}
   \caption{Results for subsection B}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `pdftex` option should not be given to `graphicx` (nor `dvips`).

Comment: I try to delete this options in OP questions, but It seem that I haven't this privilege (or don't know, how to right do this :-( ) .

Comment: @Zarko I think there should be a surgeon general's warning at the end of every float used: "Warning: floats will never end up where you want them 100% of the time". The `H` flag fails under extreme circumstances.